# How do you export a playlist in Groove Music?

Tags: groove-music

Groove Music seems doesn't appear to be able to save playlists it creates with your Microsoft Account as `.wpl` files for archive/sharing though it's able to read and play playlists that are stored as `.wpl` files.

How do you export an online playlist as a `.wpl` file?

Answer (score 1):

Groove can add songs to existing playlists including `.wpl` playlists. So, if you create an empty `.wpl` file as a text file and save it in Groove's music directory you can add all of the songs from the playlist you're attempting to export and copy the file.

Create a text file with the content below and rename it to `Export.wpl` (or any other `.wpl` name you'd like):

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
      <author/>
      <title>Export</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <seq>
        </seq>
    </body>
</smil>
```

The title is "Export" by default but this can be changed either by editing the file or renaming it in Groove Music or another music app that can edit `.wpl` files.

You can also manually edit the `.wpl` file as a text file if you'd like at any time (including after it's been populated with your selected music).

Comment: Groove doesn't seem to write to the .WPL file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Or - maybe a bit easier for some users - create a playlist with a different program like classic Windows Media Player. If both programs are opened at the same time your new playlist will appear in Groove a few seconds later. Now simply switch to Groove and add (+) your Groove-Playlist into the new one. It will need a few seconds again to synchronize your new playlist into Media Player. Switch back to Windows Media Player and right-click on your new playlist and open it on your local directory - there you´ve got your wpl-file :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a playlist I'd created under `%userprofile%\Music\Playlists\`. It was a `.zpl` file which apparently is a ["Zune Playlist"](https://www.reviversoft.com/en/file-extensions/zpl). It is a text format that looks almost exactly like XML except that it has a `<?zpl version="2.0"?>` directive on line 1, and then looks like it borrows some of the rest from HTML. Applying the [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) `//media/@src` to the document yielded me all the filenames contained in the playlist.